# CSV file read in console application and then compare their supervisor id and id then show any data in Console Application

Tags: c#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var streamReader = File.OpenText(@"C:/Samples/Vivek/ConsoleApp5/Paylocity.csv");
        using var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        while (csvReader.Read())
        {
            var CompanyName = csvReader.GetField(0);
            var Id = csvReader.GetField(1);
            var PreferredFirstName = csvReader.GetField(2);
            var FirstName = csvReader.GetField(3);
            var LastName = csvReader.GetField(4);
            var JobTitle = csvReader.GetField(5);
            var WorkPhone = csvReader.GetField(6);
            var WorkExtension = csvReader.GetField(7);
            var Email = csvReader.GetField(8);
            var Supervisor_current = csvReader.GetField(9);
            var Supervisor_ID = csvReader.GetField(10);
            var Hire_Date = csvReader.GetField(11);
            var Rehire_Date = csvReader.GetField(12);
            Console.WriteLine($"{Id}  {Supervisor_ID}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: i want to compare their values is supervisor_id and id so how to compare id in this program

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compare if the ID and the supervisor ID is the same? If both of these are Strings. you can use String.equals().

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using var streamReader = File.OpenText(@"C:/Samples/Vivek/ConsoleApp5/Paylocity.csv") 
    {
        using var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
        {
            while (csvReader.Read())
            {
                var CompanyName = csvReader.GetField(0);
                var Id = csvReader.GetField(1);
                var PreferredFirstName = csvReader.GetField(2);
                var FirstName = csvReader.GetField(3);
                var LastName = csvReader.GetField(4);
                var JobTitle = csvReader.GetField(5);
                var WorkPhone = csvReader.GetField(6);
                var WorkExtension = csvReader.GetField(7);
                var Email = csvReader.GetField(8);
                var Supervisor_current = csvReader.GetField(9);
                var Supervisor_ID = csvReader.GetField(10);
                var Hire_Date = csvReader.GetField(11);
                var Rehire_Date = csvReader.GetField(12);

                if (String.Equals(Id, Supervisor_ID) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{Id} : {Supervisor_ID}");
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont have issue with reading file i want to compare the id